# table header not geting fixed in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

below works in chromer, Firefox but not in IE8
Can anyone tell me why?

```
 table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    }

tbody {
    height: 520px;
    overflow: auto;
}
table td {
    min-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align:center;
}

thead > tr, tbody{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE8 tbody is not scrollable so use:

```
position: absolute;
```

and then use margin andpaddings for the divs etc.